# Remove one column content from another (A-B) in pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, typeerror

My pandas `dataframe` looks like this:

| tweet | hashtag |
| --- | --- |
| bla banana bla bla 23 | [banana 23] |
| bla bla apple | [apple] |

I want to perform A-B and remove the content of the hashtag column from the tweet column obtaining the following:

| tweet | hashtags |
| --- | --- |
| bla bla bla | [banana 23] |
| bla bla | [apple] |

### I have tried several ways:

with:

```
def remove_hashtags(df):
    df.tweet = [df.tweet.apply(" ".join(word)) for word in df['tweet'].apply(word_tokenize) if  word not in df['hashtags']]
    return df`
```

I get `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`
with

```
def remove_hashtags(df):
    df.tweet = [df.tweet.apply(" ".join(word)) for word in df['tweet'].apply(word_tokenize) if  word not in df['hashtags'].apply(word_tokenize)]
    return df
```

I get `TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object`.

I tried again removing potential nulls and casting everythinig to string, but would not work either.

I finally tried to `sent_tokenize` the tweet column before word tokenize it:

```
def remove_tweets(df):
    for sent in sent_tokenize(df.tweet):
        for word in word_tokenize(sent):
            df["tweet2"] = df["tweet2"].apply(" ".join(word))
    return df
```

but got again: `TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object`

I finally tried:

```
def remove_tweets(df):
    clean_text = []
    for word in word_tokenize(df.tweet):
        if word not in df.hashtags:
            clean_text.append(word)
    df['tweet2'] = clean_text
    return df
```

but got `TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object`

ps I also tried everything I mentioned after having extracted the hashtags column elements from the list through `df['hashtags'].apply(lambda x: ','.join(map(str, x)))`  but stil did not work.

Any hint?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

I would use a regular expression within a list comprehension:

```
import re
df['tweet2'] = [re.sub(fr"\b(?:{'|'.join(l)})\b", '', t)
                for t,l in zip(df['tweet'], df['hashtag'])]
```

Output (as new column tweet2 for clarity):

```
                   tweet       hashtag         tweet2
0  bla banana bla bla 23  [banana, 23]  bla  bla bla 
1          bla bla apple       [apple]       bla bla
```

To handle the spaces differently:

```
import re
df['tweet2'] = [' '.join(x for x in re.split(fr"\s*\b(?:{'|'.join(l)})\b\s*", t) if x)
                for t,l in zip(df['tweet'], df['hashtag'])]
```

Output:

```
                   tweet       hashtag       tweet2
0  bla banana bla bla 23  [banana, 23]  bla bla bla
1          bla bla apple       [apple]      bla bla
```

Comment: I tried this: it does remove the hashtag from the tweet but does not recognize it is a word, i.e. it also removes any other occurrence of the single letters. e.g. tweet: "successivamente farci amicizia torino", hashtag: "torino", output: "successvamee fac amcza". Why is that the case? Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: @duecci you need to add word boundaries (`\b`), try the update

Comment: I tried, and with both the alternatives this time the hashtag is not even removed, tweet and tweet 2 cols are the same

Comment: please update your question with this example (please, as a `DataFrame` constructor for easy reproducibility)

Comment: it worked! My hashtags column was actually a list, and I was performing this first: df['hashtags'] =  df['hashtags'].apply(lambda x: ','.join(map(str, x)))
  to extract its content. I just kept the list and it worked. Thank you so much!